# instance of mongoose.model does not have a find method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie with all of nodes and related stuff, one thing i cannot understand is why when creating a new object of a defined mongoose.model, there is no find or methods available in this new object, where as simply assigning a reference to a variable , gives me access to all methods i.e

var obj = new mongoose.model('CollectionA' ,{})
here **obj has access to only save and update methods** and nothing else
but doing **var obj = mongoose.model('CollectionA' ,{})**
gives obj access to all methods like find etc...

why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

if you invoke

```
var myElementsCollection = mongoose.model('myElementsCollection' ,{})
```

it gives you access to Model(collection). So you will be able to use find, findAll etc

if you invoke with new

`var myElements = new mongoose.model('myElementsCollection' ,{}`)

you will create specific item that goes into this collection